# XML & PHP Simple Question

Tags: php, xml

I need to add in a $person into the area were you add a value into addChild ,So it add's the value fo $person it into my xml file

$person->addChild('first_name', $person);

I know this is wrong but could some one explain why ?

Thanks

Comment: Both the context object and the second parameter are named $person. You certainly don't want to add the "complete object" to a child element. Which part of the parent element $person do you want to add to the child element $person->first_name?

Answer (score 0):

Second argument of [SimpleXMLElement::addChild](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.addChild.php) is only used for string values, like:

```
<first_name>Oliver</first_name>
```

If you have subelements in the element, you have to create them without specifying a string value (a subelement created will be returned by `addChild`), and then populate with attributes, values, and sub-elements of their own.