# How to use php value in SimpleXMLElement?

Tags: php, xml

I know that too add a text value into the xml page I do the following

```
$person = $sxe->addChild("person");
$person->addChild('first_name');
```

If I want to use the value of $person how could I code it ?

Comment: Directly related to (exact duplicate of?) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063986/xml-php-simple-question

Answer (score 0):

You can get it as

```
$personXml = $person->asXML();
```